# What to do if there currently is no tag that fits my question?

Tags: support, tags, privileges

I am wanting to ask a question about the game Slime Rancher, however there is no [slime-rancher](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slime-rancher) tag, nor any other tag which I have been able to find that has fitted my question, so what does one do in this case when one does not have enough rep to create a new tag, but currently there is no tag that fits the bill? I think that it would be very nice if there was a tag called [unknown-tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unknown-tag) which one could set their question as if they can't find any tags which fit the bill. And then obviously a user with higher rep could come and create the appropriate tag and remove this one, or could just change it to the appropriate tag if one already exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just ask your question with the tag of the platform, and add a mention of what game you are talking about. Eventually with a mention that you couldn't make the tag. And then someone else who can create tags will edit the tag in and remove your mention about the tag not existing.

We can't create a tag without a question though.